# How to return data from a subcollection document in firebase firestore V9

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

For a to-do app, I need to make a page for each subtask.
The subtasks data is stored inside the subcollection of a project.
I know the name of the subcollection and I know the the id of every document in that subcollection.

However, when I log the doc.data() for my clicked element, I get an undefined..

I am lost how to get data from subcollection documents so anyone that can help me out?

This is what I've tried, which returns undefined:

```
const returnSubtasks = async () => {
  const list = document.querySelector('#taskList');
  const listItem = document.querySelector('#listItem');
  const projectId = sessionStorage.getItem('projectId');
  const subtasks = collection(db, `projects/${projectId}/subtasks`);
  const getSubTask = await getDocs(subtasks);
  
  if (!getSubTask) {
    list!.innerHTML = `
    <h4>No current Subtasks</h4>
    `;
  }
  getSubTask.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
    const {
      title, finished, description, user, timeSpent, 
    } = doc.data();
    const item = new ListItem(doc.id, title, finished, description, user, timeSpent);
    item.render();
  });

  const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.subtaskItem');

  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    const task = tasks[i];
    console.log(task);
    task.addEventListener('click', async (e: any) => {
      if (e && e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); 
      const taskId = `${task.getAttribute('id')}`;
      console.log(taskId);
      const getMyDoc = doc(db, 'subtasks', taskId);
      const docs = await getDoc(getMyDoc);
      const id = docs.id;
      **console.log(docs.data()) -> returns undefined;**      
    });
  }
};
```

So I loop over every document inside the subcollection, I render a card for every document and loop over the rendered cards so I can make redirect to the detail page of that task.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: In the code it seems like you named the subcollection as `subtasks` which is in the `projects` collection and trying to access the subcollection. To return the data from a subcollection document you need to update the line from `const getMyDoc = doc(db, 'subtasks', taskId);` to `const getMyDoc = doc(db, 'projects/${projectId}/subtasks', taskID);`

Comment: Stef-Verniers, Let me know if the above suggestion helps you to resolve the issue.